Difference between App Signing Key and keys present in my keystore
I am developing a unity app for android that must be published on the Google Play Store. When creating the application in the Google Console, I made the mistake of letting Google manage my signing keys because I use an authentication method with Google Play Games that takes the keys present in my key store into consideration. I need to make the keys present in Google Play stop updating daily and become the same as those created by the keystore.
I accessed some articles and forums in search of solving this problem and I managed to upgrade my key in the Google Console, but every time I access it I notice that they are still not the same as those created in my keystore.
